# how can i add a button to my VCL Component

Tags: delphi, custom-component

I have created a component and now i want to add a button to it.
I tried to create Button like this:

```
constructor TUiCompU.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
inherited;

  FButton := TButton.Create(Self);
....
End;
```

but the button does not show.
How can I do that?

Comment: How is the user of your control (the programmer) intended to interact with this sub-control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only do you need to `Create()` the button but you also need to set its `Parent` property to be your component:

```
FButton.Parent := Self;
```